# Is there a reference document for GIT configuration file properties?

Tags: git

If I am interested in the meaning of a property such as "IdentitiesOnly" that I see in a GIT configuration file, where can I look it up?

Is there a reference document about the GIT configuration files, their syntax, usable properties, property values and meaning?

This question is NOT about "IdentitiesOnly", that is only an example.

This question is NOT about the git config command.

Comment: See the `git-config` man page, which is available online [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: Are you serious? Did you even bother googling for "git configuration".

Comment: ""Searching through the entire site i couldn't find your example though, IdentitiesOnly" (from the second answer). You see the problem? @Sverri M. Olsen: Did you bother reading the question?

Comment: @Gustave `IdentitiesOnly` is not a Git config key. You must be confusing `.git/config` and `.ssh/config`.

Comment: From the git-config man page: "Note that this list is non-comprehensive and not necessarily complete. For command-specific variables, you will find a more detailed description in the appropriate manual page.

Other git-related tools may and do use their own variables. When inventing new variables for use in your own tool, make sure their names do not conflict with those that are used by Git itself and other popular tools, and describe them in your documentation."

Comment: @Gustave You've just answered your own question. The man page of `git config` is as comprehensive as can be. *For command-specific variables, you will find a more detailed description in the appropriate manual page. Other git-related tools may and do use their own variables.*

Comment: That's the reason I asked about a reference document. Such a document would list all options from all related man pages. Something that is only nearly comprehensive cannot answer the question if "IdentitiesOnly" is a legal/useful GIT configuration option or just an error or maybe a variable for some obscure "git-related tool". But it seems there is no such thing (yet).

Comment: @Gustave: there cannot be a complete reference, because git's config files are free-format and people are constantly inventing new features and giving them names.  Look, there goes one now, flying by in the ether(net)! :)

Comment: @torek: Yep. So the short answer to my question is "No." Still, it would be possible to create a reference document by defining the scope (excluding external tools).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by looking at the following:

[Git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)
[Git config customization](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

The `IdentitiesOnly` is related to SSH configuration. See [ssh config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Of course I was able to find the reference page for the config command. But the question is not about that command but about the config files. If you search the text of the two pages you put for the property "IdentitiesOnly" you wll notice that it is not there. So, how is this GIT configuration property linked to ssh? Which SSH configuration properties can be used in a GIT configuration file at what place? Are there other components like SSH contributing config properties?